# How to run Fsi.exe in 64 Bits?

Tags: f#

How can I run the F# interactive window in x64 so I can load big data in it?

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe that the FSI in F# 3.0 and later includes a x64 version.

Comment: Nowadays: just click the setting in VS under Options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lukeh/archive/2008/09/17/f-september-2008-ctp-known-issues.aspx

it says

> It is possible to make F# Interactive
>   load as 64-bit by modifying fsi.exe
>   using corflags.exe. There are details
>   on this .NEt Framework SDK tool at
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699(VS.80).aspx.

but I have not tried it.  Hm, also

http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/6369.aspx

to consolidate links to possible info...

Comment: @Brian according to http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/6369.aspx this will make F# interactive window crash

Comment: Try it and see.  Another possibility is to compile your own version of FSI.exe from the source code, but target 64-bit.  I am just throwing ideas out here, I haven't tried any of this and don't know if any of it works.

Comment: @Brian so i did the thing they talk about in hubfs, and now when I look in task manager it says Fsi.exe (instead of  Fsi.exe *32). Yet Fsi.exe still cant load more than 3GB in memory. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Jon Harrop, arggg i didn't know about this, is there a way around it ?  (otherwise the fix that Brian suggests seems to be working well)

Comment: @jlezard: No, you're screwed.

Comment: With .NET 4.5, there's [a way](http://bhrnjica.net/2012/07/22/with-net-4-5-10-years-memory-limit-of-2-gb-is-over/) around that limit.

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx gives instructions on how to do it within Visual Studio 2012.

What this appears to do is run fsianycpu.exe from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\3.0\Framework\v4.0 instead of fsi.exe.  Running that from my powershell allows me to load my large data set.

Answer (score 4):

With Visual Studio 2015 and later it is as simple as this

> You can control the F# Interactive command line arguments (options) by adjusting the settings. On the **Tools** menu, select **Options...**, and then expand **F# Tools**. The two settings that you can change are the F# Interactive options and the **64-bit F# Interactive** setting, which is relevant only if you are running F# Interactive on a 64-bit machine. This setting determines whether you want to run the dedicated 64-bit version of fsi.exe or fsianycpu.exe, which uses the machine architecture to determine whether to run as a 32-bit or 64-bit process.