# .NET object size limit

Tags: .net

It seems there is a 2 GB size limit for objects in .NET: [How to run Fsi.exe in 64 Bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284381/how-to-run-fsi-exe-in-64-bits)

Is there a work around this? I would like to load a very large float array (10 GB) in memory and then do some work.

Comment: @Torben Rahbek Koch see edit thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

.NET limits any object to max 2 GB even on 64 bit platforms. You can create your own data type, that uses multiple objects to store more data, thus getting around the 2 GB limit of a single object. For instance a `List<float[]>` would allow you to store more than 2 GB, but you would have to write the necessary plumbing code to make it behave similar to a single, large array.

You may also want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087982/single-objects-still-limited-to-2-gb-in-size-in-clr-4-0).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know what are the limitations in Java and Python for example ?

Comment: @jlezard: Sorry, I can't help you with the specifics for Java and Python. IronPython would have the same limit as it runs on .NET but apart from that I can't say.

Answer (score 5):

In versions of .NET prior to 4.5, the maximum object size is 2GB. From 4.5 onwards you can allocate larger objects if [gcAllowVeryLargeObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is enabled. Note that the limit for `string` is not affected, but "arrays" should cover "lists" too, since lists are backed by arrays.

Comment: is there any upper limit to gcAllowVeryLargeObjects?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an easy workaround for this, it seems to me there could be difficulties implementing a heap without a 2Gb limit on object size.

Maybe you would be better breaking the data up some how.  It should be possible to write a class that behave like an array but splits the data up into fixed sized chunks under the hood.

Comment: With .Net 4.5 this 2 GB limit is not in the picture anymorehttps://bhrnjica.net/2012/07/22/with-net-4-5-10-years-memory-limit-of-2-gb-is-over/