# Except LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE, what else factors will limit C# process memory consumption?

Tags: c#, memory, out-of-memory, 32-bit

I take over a C# project which loads 3D models into memory, so I need large memory to use. My platform is 64-bit win10, the C# program is 32-bit, and I use visual studio 2013 to develop. My laptop have 8GB memory.
 

 
Before I use `editbin /largeaddressaware $(TargetPath)` to add LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag to the C# program, it could only consume memory approximately 1GB then program throws OutOfMemory exception, after adding LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE flag, it could consume memory approximately 1.5GB.

I know that using LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE on 32-bit process running on 64-bit platform, the memory limit is 4GB. I have also read some articles, says because .NET back-end work and memory fragment, the process is not able to really allocate memory to 4GB.

But I think 1.5GB is way too far to 4GB, so I want to ask is there any other factor will cause memory usage limit? Thank you for your answer.

Comment: .NET limits object size to max 2 GB even on 64 bit platforms. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312169/net-object-size-limit

Comment: @MitchWheat I know. but I am sure the program doesn't create GB-level objects.

Comment: @MitchWheat You're right, I retracted my comment realizing that it wasn't true for individual objects.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong memory statistic, typically caused by assuming that Task Manager gives good info.  It shows RAM usage, it is irrelevant to this problem.  It *can* show the relevant one, add the "Commit size" column.  That one represents virtual memory allocation size well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem finally. 
My C# project have some code to detect its memory usage, when it occupy memory over 1GB, it will throw OutOfMemoryException itself. After I comment these code, the program can reach memory usage to 3GB.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to debug your application, your application will not run with `LARGEADDRESSAWARE` (because the *vshost.exe* is not properly flagged).

[How to: Disable the Hosting Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330(v=vs.120).aspx)

Also, be mindful of the `GC`, it wont aggressively clean up memory in these sorts of situations. So it might be one of the few situations where it would be beneficial to call

```
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

**Additional Resouces**

[GC.Collect Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx)

[GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.waitforpendingfinalizers(v=vs.110).aspx)

Also take a look at this question if you havent

[Can I set LARGEADDRESSAWARE from within Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597790/can-i-set-largeaddressaware-from-within-visual-studio)

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I noticed this issue before. I have already unchecked `Enable the Visual Studio hosting process` in project property. This is not the reason cause my problem, but I found the reason now.