# Out of memory exception for a matrix

Tags: f#, matrix, out-of-memory, f#-interactive

I have the "'System.OutOfMemoryException" exception for this simple code (a 10 000 * 10 000 matrix) multiplied by itself:

```
#time

#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

open System
open System.IO

open Microsoft.FSharp.Math
open System.Collections.Generic


let mutable Matrix1 = Matrix.create 10000 10000 0.

let matrix4 = Matrix1 * Matrix1
```

I have the following error:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException: An exception 'System.OutOfMemoryException' has been raised
   Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array2DModule.ZeroCreate[T](Int32 length1, Int32 length2)
   Microsoft.FSharp.Math.DoubleImpl.mulDenseMatrixDS(DenseMatrix`1 a, DenseMatrix`1 b)
   Microsoft.FSharp.Math.SpecializedGenericImpl.mulM[a](Matrix`1 a, Matrix`1 b)
   <StartupCode$FSI_0004>.$FSI_0004.main@() dans C:\Users\XXXXXXX\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\Library1\Library1\Module1.fs:line 92
Stop due to an error
```

I have therefore 2 questions:

1. I have a 8 GB memory on my computer and according to my calculation a 10 000 * 10 000 matrix should take 381 MB [computed this way : `10 000 * 10 000 = 100 000 000` integers in the matrix => `100 000 000 * 4 bytes (integers of 32 bits) = 400 000 000 => 400 000 000 / (1024*1024) = 381 MB`] so I cannot understand why there is an `OutOfMemoryException`
2. More generally (it's not the case here I think), I have the impression that F# interactive registers all the data and therefore overloads the memory, do you know of a way to free all the data registered by F# interactive without exiting F#?

Comment: You have arbitrarily much *memory* in your machine; remember, disk space is memory too. RAM chips are just a fast way to cache disk memory. You could have 8GB or .5 GB or 1000GB of physical memory; it's completely irrelevant. The memory you are running out of is *per-process virtual address space*, and that has nothing to do with how much RAM or disk space you have.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In summary, `fsi` is [a 32-bit process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4284381/how-to-run-fsi-exe-in-64-bits); at most it can hold 2GB of data. Run your test as a 64-bit Windows application; you can increase the size of the matrix, but it still has [2GB limit of .NET objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312169/net-object-size-limit).

I correct your calculation a little bit. `Matrix1` is a `float matrix`, so each element occupies 8 bytes in memory. The total size of `Matrix1` and `matrix4` in memory is at least:

```
2 * 10000 * 10000 * 8 = 1 600 000 000 bytes ~ 1.6 GB
```

(ignoring some bookkeeping parts of `matrix`)

So it's no surprise when `fsi*32` runs out of memory in this case.

Execute the test as a 64-bit Windows process, you can create `float` matrices of size around `15000` but not more than that. Check out [this informative article](http://www.centerspace.net/blog/nmath/large-matrices-and-vectors/) for concrete numbers with different types of matrix elements.

Comment: There's an article here that explains how to run fsi as 64 bit process: http://ig2600.blogspot.com/2010/05/making-fsharp-interpreter-fsi-run-in.html Alternatively you could compiler your F# code and by default it would run as a 64 bit process on a 64 bit OS.

Answer (score 9):

The amount of physical memory on your computer is not the relevant bottleneck - see [Eric Lippert's great blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/08/out-of-memory-does-not-refer-to-physical-memory.aspx) for more information.